# WPF MVVM Parent and Child Grids - Update Parent from Child

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two grids, the parent grid which shows a list of 'Sections' and a child that shows a list of 'Documents'

What I want to achieve is to have a ComboBox on the child grid which can be used to change the section.

My ViewModel has the collection of Sections which the parent grid binds to, and then the child grid binds to the Documents property of the SelectedSection.

```
private ObservableCollection<Section> _sections;
public ObservableCollection<Section> Sections
{
    get => _sections;
    set => SetProperty(ref _sections, value, nameof(Sections));
}

private Section _selectedSection;
public Section SelectedSection
{
    get => _selectedSection;
    set => SetProperty(ref _selectedSection, value, nameof(SelectedSection));
}
```

To get this to behave correctly I have to wire up an event (done in the ViewModel) to every document in every section to detect if the Section has changed from the ComboBox and then manually call RaisePropertyChanged to refresh the UI.

```
//This method simply calls NotifyPropertyChanged
newDocument.DocumentSectionChanged += NewDocument_DocumentSectionChanged;
```

Is there a way I can get this refresh by itself?

Am struggling to post what code is relevant, so below is some extra code that may be relevant. Happy to post anything else, just leave a comment.

The classes for these are set-up as so:

```
public class Section : ViewModelBase, ICloneable
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
         get => _name;
         set => SetProperty(ref _name, value, nameof(Name));
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Document> _documents;
    public ObservableCollection<Document> Documents
    {
         get => _documents;
         set => SetProperty(ref _documents, value, nameof(Documents));
    }
}
```

and the Document class:

```
public class Document : ViewModelBase, ICloneable
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Description")]
    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set => SetProperty(ref _description, value, nameof(Description));
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Date")]
    private DateTime _date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get => _date;
        set => SetProperty(ref _date, value, nameof(Date));
    }

    private Section _section;
    public Section Section
    {
        get => _section;
        set
        {
            var eventArgs = new DocumentSectionChangedEventArgs();
            eventArgs.OldSection = _section;
            SetProperty(ref _section, value, nameof(Section));
            eventArgs.NewSection = value;
            DocumentSectionChanged?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DocumentSectionChangedEventArgs> DocumentSectionChanged;  
}
```

Here is the part of the XAML for the parent grid.

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="sectionGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Sections, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSection}" SelectionMode="Row">
```

and here is part of the child grid.

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="documentsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSection.Documents}" Grid.Row="1">
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Section" Header="Section" Width="Auto">
        <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl>
                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="PART_Editor" ItemsSource="{Binding View.DataContext.Sections}" DisplayMember="Name" ShowBorder="False" />
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant XAML?

Comment: It's hard to get what exactly happens without XAML but I can guess that you don't need a firing of the event but bind your `ComboBox` with its `Style` to separate Property that will fire `PropertyChanged` event itself when you changing the selected value. Then you may bind your 2nd `DataGrid`'s state to that Property through `Converter`.

Comment: I have added what parts I believe are relevant, if you would like to see anything else please let me know. :)